# What happens when clearTimeout is called on a variable with setTimeout on it?

Tags: javascript

So, what I mainly was wondering, was if `clearTimeout(t);` is the same as `t = undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to test out for yourself.  Here's a fiddle where you can see that Axel is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/s3sUU/.

Answer (score 2):

No, the value returned by setTimeout is just a number, a primitive type, and it's just used like an "index" or "identifier" when used in clearTimeout. But it's not a pointer to the function.